# Can a character use a quickened action during an AoO?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack

I can't quite figure out how this works:

I caused an AoO and an enemy dragon used a quickened breath weapon (free action) on me as an AoO, while the rule states that an AoO is a single melee attack...

Was that breath legal?

Comment: Note for anyone else reading this: Quicken Breath Weapon from the Draconomicon turns the subject's breath weapon into a *free action* -- this is different from the normal Quicken Spell feat!

Comment: A detailed and pedantic examination of the legality of off-turn free actions is [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/33319/8610). (*Caution:* May cause fist fights and table flips.)

Comment: If you could find a way to make it an Immediate Action, then it is possible.

Answer (score 9):

No.  As you note, an AoO is a single melee attack; [quickened abilities, as they are free actions, can only be used on your turn](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm).

However, GM's world, GM's rules, so I would take it with good humor if it's a home game and not Organized Play of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

No, because a breath weapon is not a *melee attack*.

Usually, a move action or free action can always be made in place of a standard action, but in case of Attack of Opportunity, that action has to be a melee attack.