# Is an attack of opportunity triggered by maintaining a grapple?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, grapple

Scenario:
A character **A** is maintaining a grapple of another character **B** (who is currently stunned). The grapple has already been initiated the round before.
A third character **C** is in melee distance of **A**.

During **A**'s turn, **A** takes either the "Attack Your Opponent" or "Damage Your Opponent" option from the actions that can be taken while in a grapple.

Is **C** allowed to make a attack of opportunity on **A**?

I haven't found any clues in the description of grappling. Another source I found is table 8-2, “Combat Actions”, in the PHB that states for a Grapple either:

1. > (1) Regardless of the action, if you move out of a threatened square, you usually provoke an attack of opportunity. **This column indicates whether the action itself, not moving, provokes an attack of opportunity.**
2. > (7) These attack forms **substitute for a melee attack**, not an action. As melee attacks, they can be used once in an attack or charge action, one or more times in a full attack action, or even as an attack of opportunity.

It's seems to me that the bolded parts clash, the first granting a generic AoO and the second denying a generic AoO.

Also, others questions about grappling in almost same situation:

1. **C** attacks **A** with success: does the grapple on **B** end? [no, in my understanding, grapple is independent from damage taken by winning grappler]
2. **C** joins the grapple **A** [automatically]: how the grapple on **B** can end?
3. Another character **D** performs a winning Bull Rush on **A**. Does the grapple on **B** end? [In my understanding, **D** is bull-rushing both of them]

Comment: Your question title refers to *maintaining* a grapple, but your question's text and the answer you accepted both refer to initiating a grapple. Could you clarify what you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Table 8–2: [Actions in Combat](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/actionsInCombat.html#actions-in-combat) (*Player's Handbook* 141) indicates that a grapple provokes attacks of opportunity, it's indicating that *making a grapple attempt to start a grapple* typically provokes attacks of opportunity. A creature that wants to grapple actually obeys the longer and more detailed rules for the special attack [Grapple](http://Grapple) (*PH* 155-7), the table providing only a summary. Other actions listed in the section [If You're Grappling](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#grapple-activate-a-magic-item) provoke attacks of opportunity *only* if those actions say they do, *not*—if following *only* the table—for every action taken *during* a grapple.

- If Creature C makes a successful attack against Creature A, unless Creature A is slain by the attack, Creature A and Creature B continue grappling normally.
- The [Joining a Grapple](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#joining-a-grapple) rules would have Creature C participate in the grapple normally. Creature C's presence adds a layer of complication to the grapple, but doesn't change fundamentally how grapple works.
- The special attack [bull rush](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#bull-rush) affects only one creature: "When you make a bull rush, you attempt to push *an opponent* straight back instead of damaging him" (*PH* 154 and emphasis mine). If Creature C were to succeed on a bull rush against either Creature A or Creature B, their grapple likely ends.

Comment: Are you (and rules) speaking about "inside grappling" or "outside grappling". My question is driven by : if an AoO is defined as "__Sometimes a combatant in a melee lets her guard down. In this case, combatants near her can take advantage of her lapse in defense to attack her for free.__", my interpretation is grappling anyone falls in this case because grappler combatant  direct her attention to stunned grappled. So combatant outside grapple has free meal. Grappled and stunned grappled cannot react in any manner. Is someone outside the grapple able to do AoO (by RAW) to grappling combatants?

Comment: Kudos for bull rush. It's pretty convincing!

for 2. I don't understand HOW AND IF  C, joining the grapple, may break (by RAW) "A grapple B" condition. [It's not important if after this A is grappling C or viceversa]

Comment: @Pulz That quotation describes broadly some situations in which an attack of opportunity *may* occur, but attempts to play attacks of opportunity based on that *alone* will lead to sorrow and confusion. *Starting* a grapple typically provokes attacks of opportunity, but performing actions while grappling provoke attacks of opportunity only when the action listed in [If You're Grappling](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#grapple-activate-a-magic-item) says the action provokes.

Comment: @Pulz In other words, Creature C can make an attack of opportunity when Creature A and Creature B are in a grapple *only* when Creature A or Creature B do something else that provokes an attack of opportunity. The fact that they're grappling *in and of itself* doesn't cause Creature A and Creature B to provoke attacks of opportunity.

Comment: @Pulz Finally, when Creature C joins Creature A and Creature B in a grapple that's already in progress, *all three* of the creatures are now grappling. Creature C joining their grapple does not end the grapple between Creature A and Creature B! (In my campaigns, 3 or more creatures in a grapple is known as a  *grapple ball*, and it can get hilarious.)

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

The rules for making an attack in a grapple are as follows:

> ### Attack Your Opponent
>
> You can make an attack with an unarmed strike, natural weapon, or
> light weapon against another character you are grappling. You take a
> -4 penalty on such attacks.
>
> You can’t attack with two weapons while grappling, even if both are
> light weapons.
>
> ### Damage Your Opponent
>
> While grappling, you can deal damage to your opponent equivalent to an
> unarmed strike. Make an opposed grapple check in place of an attack.
> If you win, you deal nonlethal damage as normal for your unarmed
> strike (1d3 points for Medium attackers or 1d2 points for Small
> attackers, plus Strength modifiers). If you want to deal lethal
> damage, you take a -4 penalty on your grapple check.
>
> Exception: Monks deal more damage on an unarmed strike than other
> characters, and the damage is lethal. However, they can choose to deal
> their damage as nonlethal damage when grappling without taking the
> usual -4 penalty for changing lethal damage to nonlethal damage.

There is no mention of either of these actions triggering an opportunity attack - so this is treated as a normal attack, except for the -4 modifier and the restrictions on which weapons can be used. However, Table: Miscellaneous Actions in the Actions in Combat section says that taking the special Grapple action itself provokes an attack of opportunity; so **C** can make an attack of opportunity. **A** will also lose their Dexterity bonus to AC against **C**'s attack. **C** can choose to have their attack be joining the grapple, if they want.

*(Thanks to @Ols for pointing out that **B** being grappled prevents them from making attacks of opportunity.)*

To answer your other points briefly:

1. Taking damage doesn't affect a grapple unless it reduces you to 0 or
   fewer hit points.
2. If **C** joins the grapple, they become part of the
   grapple, but they are on **B**'s side, so **B** still needs to do the
   same thing to escape the grapple. **B** needs to (as their action)
   choose to "Escape from Grapple" and then score higher on their
   grapple check than any opponent in the grapple that tries to stop
   them. (If **E** was helping **A** grapple **B**, **B** would have to beat
   both **A** and **E**'s opposed rolls to successfully escape the
   grapple.) If **B** passes this grapple check, he moves out of the
   grapple space into an adjacent space of their choice.
3. This case isn't explicitly covered by the rules, as far as I can tell.

(If you want more detail on these points, you should probably make them their own question.)

Comment: B would NOT be allowed to make an attack of opportunity because he would be in a grapple and thus would not be threatening any square. (Provoking an Attack of Opportunity
Two kinds of actions can provoke attacks of opportunity: moving out of a threatened square and performing an action within a threatened square.)

Comment: RE: "C can choose to have their attack [of opportunity] be joining the grapple, if they want." Also see [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33301/8610).